# Excel formula to sum the total for a specific person in a specific month

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, worksheet-function

I need help with an Excel formula that sums the total or work for a specific person in a specific month. Here is what my data looks like:

[image: spreadsheet]

I need to setup a formula to extract automatically the sum of hours worked for every employee, for every month. Right now I am doing it manually, and I am not so good in Excel, I am just a beginner.

I need to be able to visualize this result:

```
Month     name       total
september K,O        0,5
october   K,O        9
october   M,R        5,5
[etc]
```

Comment: What does this data represent? You're a little vague in your explanation...

Comment: Cell A1 = **01-10-2013**

To display the Month of cell A1 as 'October' you use `=TEXT(MONTH(A1), "mmmm")`

Comment: Are you asking how to change the the way the data is displayed from one to the other? If so, what is the total (how do you come by it)? Is the information in the first 'table' 3 columns or just 1?

Comment: @DaveRook I'm pretty sure the commas are decimal separators. `0,5` is the same as `0.5`. Hence, the sum is 1 (although... the first record is not in October).

Comment: @Excellll, you're probably correct but the question is still vague sadly and it makes it hard to help

Comment: Hi Thanx for the comments, this is employee work time planner, here employee name is K,O and his work time is 0,5 (0,5 is same as 0.5). i will be entering new data everyday, so i need to mark the entire column. @DaveRook

Answer (score 4):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT` to get a sum with multiple conditions.

```
SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$1:$A$6)=10)*($C$1:$C$6="K,O")*$B$1:$B$6)
```

The columns referred to here match your sample data. You can substitute cell references for the month and name values you're matching.

**EDIT:**

To match the month by name rather than number, you can use the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((TEXT($A$1:$A$6,"Mmmm")="October")*($C$1:$C$6="K,O")*$B$1:$B$6)
```

Comment: I'm lost why you're hard coding K and O (or did I missunderstand your code)

Comment: @DaveRook It's hardcoded because I don't know how his sheet is layed out. He can plug in cell references for those values.

Comment: Ah, I see. Cool! Sorry, I didn't think of that!